# How can i write this object in a hdf5 file with java

Tags: java, hdf5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBT0N.png)
I need to write this object with use hdf5 compound,but i don't know how to write array with use compound. I need help please.

```
public class Sensor {
    public int index;
    public double [] value_block_0;
    public String [] value_block_1;
    public long [] value_block_2;
    public String time;
    public String code;

    public Sensor(int index, double [] value_block_0, String [] value_block_1, long [] value_block_2, String time,
            String code) {
        super();
        this.index = index;
        this.value_block_0 = value_block_0;
        this.value_block_1 = value_block_1;
        this.value_block_2 = value_block_2;
        this.time = time;
        this.code = code;
    }
```

}

```
object_data[0] = new Sensor(115300, arr1, arr2, arr3, "09:31:00", "200001");
    object_data[1] = new Sensor(118400, arr1, arr2, arr3, "09:32:00", "200001");
    object_data[2] = new Sensor(102700, arr1, arr2, arr3, "09:33:00", "200001");
    object_data[3] = new Sensor(131300, arr1, arr2, arr3, "09:34:00", "200001");
    object_data[4] = new Sensor(123400, arr1, arr2, arr3, "09:35:00", "200001");
    object_data[5] = new Sensor(357600, arr1, arr2, arr3, "09:36:00", "200001");
```

I'm trying to use H5 api write object_data into hdf5 file, but failed.

```
if ((dataset_id >= 0) && (memtype_id >= 0))
            H5.H5Dwrite((int)dataset_id, (int)memtype_id, HDF5Constants.H5S_ALL, HDF5Constants.H5S_ALL,
                    HDF5Constants.H5P_DEFAULT, object_data);
```

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? What have you tried?

Comment: Please include the code/description in the question as text. Images can't be searched on, nor can they be used in reading software for those of us with bad eyesight.